# sap.ui.comp.valuehelp.ValueHelpDialog - value for parameter 'aArgs' is not of type array

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

After upgrading UI5 from 1.108 to 1.119, we've started seeing the error below in our value help dialogs (sap.ui.comp.valuehelp.ValueHelpDialog).
*sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle: value for parameter 'aArgs' is not of type array -  *

This can be reproduced with the following sample, by opening the dialog and switching to the Define Conditions tab:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.recommended

It seems like there was a change in the implementation of the _formatValue function in ResourceBundle, which now requires that aArgs be either undefined or an array.

In the example from the sample [the number items is passed as a string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRIyS.png), while [the condition operators have null as a parameter for aArgs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOSHb.png).

Similar issues were reported in the openUI5 GitHub, though the sap.ui.comp library is not part of openUI5.
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3924
https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3890

As far as I have seen, this does not impact the usability of the dialog but it does flood the console with errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [...] the `_formatValue` function in `ResourceBundle`, which now requires that `aArgs` be either undefined or an array.

The [`ResourceBundle#getText`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/module:sap/base/i18n/ResourceBundle%23methods/getText) API has always been requiring the `aArgs` argument to be an array. It's the consuming code that misaligned with the API reference. Only the error log is new. The log itself is not a breaking change (at least not in UI5 1.x) since it's simply a console log rather than throwing a real `Error`.

The issue should be already fixed by now in the affected `sap.ui.comp` library modules.

If you need the fix to be downported to the [maintained SAPUI5 releases](https://ui5.sap.com/versionoverview.html), consider creating a [customer ticket](https://me.sap.com/getsupport) (component: CA-UI5-CMP).

Comment: In which version is this fixed? The error is still logged on the latest (1.120.6) version, e.g.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog/sample/sap.ui.comp.sample.valuehelpdialog.recommended    

Indeed the error is not breaking but in some cases (define conditions for an integer field) it is logged 150 times which can hide other useful information.

Comment: @eliash Yes, it is very annoying. In my view, the fix should be downported to the long-term version 1.120 at least. Please create a ticket. Btw. the monthly release version 1.119 is already out of maintenance.

Comment: Thank you. We are planning to upgrade to 1.120 in any case. Just to confirm then, do we need a customer ticket even for releasing the fix on 1.120?

Comment: @eliash Yes, I'd recommend to create a ticket. Without any request, it is less likely that the fix gets downported. There might be other customers having already requested the same but wouldn't hurt. The support will then probably let you know whether such a downport was already requested or is even planned.